# tornado: UIModule for including minified javascript

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I'd like to build a Tornado `UIModule` which would allow me to include a Javascript file but *minify* it before rendering.  E.g.

> {% module include_jsmin("file.js") %}

My only problem is that I don't seem to find an elegant way to grab hold of the Template Loader for the application.

How would I do that?

**Edit**:  I know about the `render_string` method in the `UIModule` but unfortunately the configured path to the templates isn't available.

Comment: Minification is pretty expensive. Are you sure you want to do it on request and not during a pre-deploy build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a neat way:

-Configure the tornado application with a `tornado.template.Loader` using the setting `template_loader` : make sure to specify the absolute path to the root of your template dir

-Use the `render_string` in the `UIModule` to grab hold of file you wish to process

```
class JsonMinify(UIModule):    
    def render(self, path):
        code=self.render_string(path)
        return slimit.minify(code)
```